# Formatting a String to have a string with the words/numbers in line

Tags: java, string

So I am trying to create function that returns a String. The String starts off with the inputed word, then a certain number of spaces, and then a number. The number of spaces varies based on the length of the word. The idea is that all the words and numbers should be in line when the method is called multiple times. I have a picture of how I would like the String to be formatted.

[Format Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZJSf.png)

This is the function I currently have. When I type several random words and numbers into the function and use a printLn statement each time, the function works correctly and prints as I would like it to be formatted (or as shown above in the example)

```
public String formatList(String x, int y){
    String z = x;
    int stringLength=x.length();
    int i=0;
    while(i<(30-stringLength)){
     z+=" ";
     i++;
    }
    z+=String.valueOf(y);
    return z;
}
```

However, when I have a for loop enter a list of words and numbers, and add it to a JTextArea titled wordList, I get the following (note that the wordDistribution is an object I defined that is essentially an ArrayList of map entries  and getDistribution is a function that returns this ArrayList)
:

```
String x="";

for(int i=0; i<wordDistribution.getDistribution().size();i++){
        String word = wordDistribution.getDistribution().get(i).getKey();
        int count = wordDistribution.getDistribution().get(i).getValue();
        x+=formatList(word,count)+"\n";
    }
    wordList.setText(x);
```

[Resulting format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXWmq.png)

Comment: Why not just populate the data into a table and set the alignment on your td's?  You wont have to worry about spaces. The table will align your content for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), e.g.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
buf.append(String.format("%-20s%4d%n", "Foo", 42));
buf.append(String.format("%-20s%4d%n", "Hello World", 11));
buf.append(String.format("%-20s%4d%n", "This is Great", 999));
System.out.print(buf);
```

*Output*

```
Foo                   42
Hello World           11
This is Great        999
```

Comment: Fine: StringBuilder is more efficient (faster) than String +.